# How to deal with questions with no response from the asker?

Tags: discussion

I see many questions in SO where someone just asks the question and totally forgets about it. Many questions have comments trying to clarify the question but as there is no response from the asker it is not possible to answer them.

My question is what should we (as moderator) do? Should we flag such question for closing as they are not contributing here? Or should we flag them as low quality? Or should we just ignore them?

There are many questions with answers (albeit not accepted) but I feel we should not do anything about them.

But there are also many with answers trying to clarify the question.

Well may be this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309946/browser-simulation-using-htmlunildriver) will help to express my doubts better. What should we do of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309946/browser-simulation-using-htmlunildriver) question? And the ones similar to it.

Comment: Or we just down vote them???

Comment: bad question + bad answer = close

Comment: If it's not a question which should be closed because of any of the regular reasons, there is not really anything we should do IMO. "The OP seems to have left" is not a valid reason on its own to take any action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the question is too broad, then it could be closed as "not a real question." The fact the OP doesn't answer to any comment is not a reason for closing the question, if not in the case one of the closing reasons really applies to the question, which could also be closed as too localized, if the question is about a bug/issue nobody else is able to reproduce (and the OP is not giving more details that allows to reproduce the issue/bug).
If the question cannot be closed, it can still be down-voted if it is not useful, it doesn't show any effort, or it is unclear.

Apart that, there is nothing else that can be done.
Keep in mind that questions are automatically deleted (every week), if they are one-month old, without answers, and with a negative score.

Comment: "_Apart that, there is nothing else that can be done. Keep in mind that questions are automatically deleted (every week), if they are one-month old, without answers, and with a negative score._"

I did not know that. That answers my query as I was thinking that otherwise SO will be full of junk in future.